# How to save the results of loops-IDL

Tags: loops, for-loop, idl-programming-language

```
Change=[[N_elements(Change92_2001)],N_elements(Change92_2006),N_elements(Change92_2010)]
T=3
  FOR i=0,T-1 DO BEGIN
   area=Change[i]*900
   print,area
   help,area
 ENDFOR
```

I am trying to write a basic loop that will look at the number of pixels within certain images and then calculate the area of change within each image. 
How do I save the results of the loop into a new array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `area` an array:

```
area = fltarr(t)
for i = 0, t - 1 do begin
  area[i] = change[i] * 900
endfor
```

And, of course, in this case the easiest way would be to just do:

```
area = change * 900
```